# JMeter Exceptions Java.net.BindException during Test Execution window

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have been trying to execute 10 Test scenarios together for 1 hr. We are observing so many HTTP samplers are failing with the exception of **Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException/Non HTTP response message: Address already in use: connect**

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check the link,it may help you or give some direction...It seems you have the similar problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194783/apache-multiple-requests-with-jmeter

Comment: Thank you for the response @sunny_teo. I have followed the same steps with this article https://www.baselogic.com/2011/11/23/solved-java-net-bindexception-address-use-connect-issue-windows/but no luck but still I'm observing same issue java.net.BindException

Comment: you can test this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194783/apache-multiple-requests-with-jmeter/14200374